# How to avoid the blinking of gradient background in IE8/9 when mouse hover

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

When I apply the following CSS to the IE8/9, and mouse over the empty area, the background will be blinking.

Here is the HTML

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="content" href="javascript:;">
                Please mouse over after the words
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="content" href="javascript:;">
                Please mouse over after the words
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS setting

```
ul {
    list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; position: relative;
}
li {
    padding: 0px; position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.content:hover {
    margin: 0;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e3f4fd', endColorstr='#c7e9f9',GradientType=0 );
}
```

You can run the example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yy3y/)

Comment: Looking from GH and nothing happens at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try and give it a solid background colour by default

http://jsfiddle.net/9yy3y/7/

```
.content {
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;

    background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Yes, add the solid background color can solve this issue for IE8/9.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this too. Just added a solid background color and this solved the flickering issue on mouseover in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get around this by adding the .content class to your list items, and targeting the `a` tags inside the list in your CSS.

**Html:**

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
<ul>
    <li class="content">
        <a href="#">
            Please mouse over after the words
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
        <a href="#">
            Please mouse over after the words
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; position: relative;
}
li {
    padding: 0px; position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content a {
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.content:hover a {
    margin: 0;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e3f4fd',     endColorstr='#c7e9f9',GradientType=0 );
}
```

**Working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9yy3y/8/

This eliminates the flicker in IE9 - I can't test any lower as JSFiddle doesn't like IE9's emulation for 8 or 7. (Or doesn't support them at all...)